# Zero divisors in the image of $\mathbb{Q} [X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\phi$ $: \mathbb{Q} [X]\rightarrow K$ be a nontrivial ring homomorphism.  Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Q} [X]$ is an integral domain.  I've been trying to show that $im(\phi)$ has no zero divisors.  I know this is not true in general, since for example $\mathbb{Z/nZ}$ has zero divisors if $n$ is not prime, but I'm really stuck on why it it's true in this particular case.

Comment: Normally when we say '$K$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$', we mean that $K$ is a *field extension* of $\mathbb Q$ and in particular that $K$ is a field.  A field never contains zero divisors (why not?) and the same goes for any subring of a field - in this case, $\text{im}\phi\subset K$.

Comment: Thanks @Donkey_2009.  I should have gone to the definition first, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x), q(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$.  Then $\deg(p q) \geq \max\{ \deg p, \deg q\}$.  So the only way $pq=0$ is if $p=0$ and $q=0$.  This tells us what's going on in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Now, if $\phi(pq) = 0$, we have $\phi(pq) = 0 = \phi(0)$...

Can that be strong enough to show that $\phi(x^2) \neq 0$?  For instance, what happens in the projection $\phi:\Bbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

As @Donkey_2009 pointed out, an algebraic extension is by definition a field, so $K$ is a field.  Since $im(\phi)$ is a subring of $K$, it inherits the structural property that it contains no zero divisors.